# How to installi Nokogiri after failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I tried to resolve the issues with some of the suggestions provided by other people having the same/similar issue, however none of them seem to have worked.  I  also followed Nokogiri's website to install it separately.
I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

I also tried:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

I also updated the system using:

```
gem update --system
```

with no luck

Error in terminal:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/johnarvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7/ext/nokogiri
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20191224-8577-xanoms.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.


Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
  --help
  --clean
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
  from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
  from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:532:in `with_werror'
  from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
  from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
  from extconf.rb:162:in `block in add_cflags'
  from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:643:in `with_cflags'
  from extconf.rb:161:in `add_cflags'
  from extconf.rb:416:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/johnarvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.7/mkmf.log
```

mkmf.log file:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I.    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wrestrict -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable  -fPIC  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,'/../lib' -Wl,-rpath,'/../lib' -lruby  -lm   -lc "
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmisleading-indentation'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wrestrict'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

`gem env` output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/johnarvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/johnarvi/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/johnarvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/johnarvi/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/johnarvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
     - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/johnarvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin
     - /home/johnarvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/bin
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin
     - /home/johnarvi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/bin
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I've had problems with a ruby-2.6.3 installed with rvm and installing some gems.  It might be worth installing the latest version of rvm with "rvm get stable" and then removing and reinstalling ruby-2.6.3. (Or install a newer version of ruby).

Comment: can you update your question to include the output of `gem env` ?

Comment: We need to see the output of `gem env`.

Comment: @BenTrewern I think I have the latest version of RVM

Comment: @lacostenycoder Sorry for the delay. tried to reinstall a bunch of things. I have added the GEM ENV output.

Comment: @theTinMan I have edited my question to show the gem env output.

Comment: How did you install RVM? Was it following "https://rvm.io/rvm/install"? What does `rvm list rubies` output? It looks like you have two Rubies, but we can't tell which you're using as your default. RVM's documentation is very thorough and I highly recommend reading at least https://rvm.io/workflow/examples.

Comment: I followed this tutorial. Step 3 `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` is what I used to get rvm [latest-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-latest-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu/)                         
 `=* ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Are you using a very old gcc?

Comment: @simonwo ubuntu version 18.04, gc version, gcc (Homebrew GCC 5.5.0_5) 5.5.0

Comment: At least one of those warnings `-Wduplicated-cond` is only available in GCC 6.0. Can you update your gcc version?

Comment: @simonwo I tired updating it using this [method](https://tuxamito.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_newer_GCC_versions_in_Ubuntu) but I get an error. Currently looking at how to fix it